# Range of models ORM django

Tags: python, django, orm

how can I add range base ORM of some models?

```
from .models import UsersLog
if request.method == 'POST':
    login = request.POST.get('flogin')
    response_data = {}
    response_data['result'] = 'Failed'
    lengthBase = UsersLog.objects.get()
    for i in lengthBase: // I got 3 users so I want lengthBase equal 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop over the UsersLog, try `lengthBase = UsersLog.objects.all()`.

Or if you just want to get the number of userslog, try

```
lengthBase = UsersLog.objects.count() 
for i in range(lengthBase):
```